# How do I remove a package from android.jar?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on an android application that uses the semantics3 api.  Included in the semantics3 library is the org.json package which is crucial to the functionality.  The code using org.json classes and functions is all included in the api and works standalone from the android application.

The problem, as far as I can tell, is that android.jar also includes a package named org.json, but it has less functionality than the semantics3 org.json.  When trying to call the semantics3 api within the app, I get the following error:

```
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONTokener.<init>
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.semantics3.api.Semantics3Request.fetch(Semantics3Request.java:70)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.semantics3.api.Semantics3Request.runQuery(Semantics3Request.java:143)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.semantics3.api.Semantics3Request.get(Semantics3Request.java:162)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.semantics3.api.Semantics3Request.get(Semantics3Request.java:154)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.semantics3.api.Products.getProducts(Products.java:21)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.cs194.windowshopping.ProductSearch.findKeywordSearchResults(ProductSearch.java:132)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.cs194.windowshopping.ProductSearch.queryByPicture(ProductSearch.java:66)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.cs194.windowshopping.ResultsActivity$PopulateResultList.doInBackground(ResultsActivity.java:116)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at com.cs194.windowshopping.ResultsActivity$PopulateResultList.doInBackground(ResultsActivity.java:1)
05-22 12:06:07.058: W/System.err(6108):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-22 12:06:07.068: W/System.err(6108):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-22 12:06:07.068: W/System.err(6108):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-22 12:06:07.068: W/System.err(6108):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-22 12:06:07.068: W/System.err(6108):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-22 12:06:07.068: W/System.err(6108):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I guess my question is how do I make sure that my application uses the right org.json package?  Or how do I remove the org.json package from android.jar, so that only the one in semantics3.jar exists?

Comment: If you have 2 of the same packages you should be able to specify which one to import when you are adding a class to your code. You can also manually type in which package to choose at the very top of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork the project at GitHub: https://github.com/Semantics3/semantics3-java

The software is MIT-licensed so you could **repackage** org.json in semantics3 (e.g. rename it to org.jsonplus) and then you shouldn't have any problems on Android. With a good Java IDE this only takes a minute or so. Of course you have to change your client code as well to use the new packages.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess my question is how do I make sure that my application uses the right org.json package?

You don't. The firmware always wins. You will use Android's copy of `org.json`, whether you like it or not.

You are welcome to remove the `org.json` classes from your third-party JAR and hope that what they used is compatible with Android's own copy. If not, complain to the vendor that they need to ship an Android-compatible version of their JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* try to remove a class from android.jar because other things in the system may need it, such as the vendor provided apps.  I had this same exact problem with org.json on older motorola and htc devices before.

Solutions:

1. Use jarjar to mangled the path in the jar file.
2. OR Repackage it manually as hgoebl. mentioned.

JarJar method

```
java -jar jarjar.jar process rulesFile.txt semantics3.jar semantics3-jarjar.jar
```

rulesFile.txt

```
rule org.json.@1 rule org.json.jarjar.@1
```

JarJar https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/CommandLineDocs

There are maven plugins to automate this.